# Manage custom content blocks on a page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm putting together my own Wordpress theme for a very specific set of client requirements. I'm fine with front-end theme work, but I need some help with back end.

The task is kind of like a support site, with lots of Q and A's. I'm building a support site for a company, which means most Pages will be populated with many questions and associated answers.

The page Structure would be something like this:

```
Home Page (with links to Most recent Q+As added) and common sections
-How to use the app (10-20 Q+As on page)
-How to manage integrations (10-20 Q+As on page)
-Other page (10-20 Q+As on page)
-5-10x 'Other pages'
About Us
Contact Support
```

**Requirements and my comments**

*-Each Q and A does not have it's own URL*

This makes using Posts for Q and A's unattractive.

*-Each Page is made up of a Table of Contents which allows quick scrolling to questions*

 An ideal solution would be some code on the page theme template which grabs each "Q and A" object within a certain category/section/identifier and load it to the page

*-New questions and answers can quickly and easily be added*

 The ideal solution for support reps is that they can add a question and answer, and assign a category, rather than edit a huge page of questions.

*-Order of Q and A's on page is important*
Ideal solution should allow you to order the Q+As within their given category/section/other.

*-On the home page, most recent Q+As added list exists*

*-Each Page of Q+As has a "last updated" date, which is the date the most recent Q+A was most recently modified.*

---

**Ideas I had**

Posts or custom posts seemed like a good idea, but they create permalinks. But my "Pages" would actually be Category Archive pages. We don't want a Q+A to be be assigned two categories. Also, custom post ordering seems difficult. If we could suppress permalinks and ensure on category or section and find a way to order them - this could work.

**FAQ Plugins**

It seems like these all are a bit clunky and the amount of custom dev to re-skin on it might not be worth it, might be easier to do something totally custom.

**Question:**

 does anyone have any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: I think you should use your own db table structure and implement db functions that add/edit/delete Q&A,categories, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use custom post types. Basically two custom post types, question and answer. Then each question can have categories tags and so on. Answers can have a custom field with question ID so you can easily get all the answers by question ID. If you need then not to have unique url, than create two files: single-question.php and single-answer.php and put 404 page code there so if user will get to the url of a single question or answer than he will see 404 error :)